# How to transform numb string to shorter version, and then back to normal form?

Tags: javascript, string, encoding

I have string of numbers, like '1324436234235464234'. I need to transform this string to something like '5R2f2t4', or other symbol sequence, not very long, all this has to be implemented on client. After this transformation, it's needed to transform it back on server side(node.js).

It looks like encryption/decryption task, but in this case I don't care about security. Is it possible to implement this sequence of transformations?

UPDATE: I can't use DB.

Comment: You could save the short code, and long code in a database.

Comment: Zip and unzip?.

Comment: Is the original always exactly as long as what you’ve shown (19 digits)? Which characters can the shortened version use, and does it have to be exactly 7 characters (“not very long” is kind of vague)? Maybe you can say what you’re using it for anyway instead of just “it has sense”.

Comment: The initial string has always the same length, and output should be at least shorter than this. I developed re-director for business purposes. The flow is:

-create link to redirector, that contains transformed string as parameter

-when user comes to redirector, it reads parameter, transforms to initial form and does some stuff.

I don't want to plug database only for this purposes, so I'm looking for another way.

Comment: I guess you are looking for Compression?

Comment: I've looked for a big number library that can parse a string and then encode the number to hex or bytes, but I've been unsuccessful so far. That seems to me a better option than compression and encoding. It should be faster *and* result in a smaller encoding most of the time.

Comment: Okay, but is it *19* digits, or much longer than that? The currently accepted answer doesn’t seem to work well for such short strings. And again: which characters can the shortened version use?

Comment: Yeap, input string always is 19 numbers. I don't care about characters set.  I marked @Ikari answer as solution, because it seems there is no algorithm for making string shorter with possibility to get initial string, but that snippet helped me partially. This time I see only one solution - use DB. 

And yes - I'll unmark that answer as a solution, because it is not, probably there is no solution that does exactly what I wont.

Comment: I mean, it seems impossible to such kind of transformation, with ability to get initial string. As I said, unfortunately I can't use DB, will try to change business logic instead. But maybe, there is solution to make it shorter from 19 to 14? Will be glad to any compression, even for several symbols.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply – I didn’t get a notification. Are you sure you don’t care about the character set? Are emoji okay, for example? 1324436234235464234 → ``Zéか\`` is fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your input string is always the same length, you can do a conversion from decimal to some other higher base.

Converting to the short form:

```js
const encode = (alphabetString, input) => {
    const alphabet = Array.from(alphabetString);

    const digits = input.split('').map(Number);
    const result = [];

    for (;;) {
        let isZero = true;

        // Divide the number in `digits` by the alphabet size
        let carry = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            const digit = 10 * carry + digits[i];

            if (digit !== 0) {
                isZero = false;
            }

            digits[i] = digit / alphabet.length >>> 0;
            carry = digit % alphabet.length;
        }

        if (isZero) {
            break;
        }

        result.push(alphabet[carry]);
    }

    return result.reverse().join('') || alphabet[0];
};

const ALPHABET = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

console.log(encode(ALPHABET, '1324436234235464234'));
```

The conversion back with `BigInt` support (i.e. you’re using Node.js 10):

```js
const decode = (alphabet, input) => {
    const map = new Map(
        Array.from(alphabet, Array.of)
    );

    const fromBase = BigInt(alphabet.length);
    let value = 0n;

    for (const c of input) {
        value = fromBase * value + BigInt(map.get(c));
    }

    return String(value);
};

const ALPHABET = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

console.log(decode(ALPHABET, '1Zpvmcf1O26').padStart(19, '0'));
```

The conversion back without `BigInt` support:

```js
const decode = (alphabet, input) => {
    const map = new Map(
        Array.from(alphabet, Array.of)
    );

    const digits = Array.from(input, c => map.get(c));
    const result = [];

    for (;;) {
        let isZero = true;
        let carry = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            const digit = alphabet.length * carry + digits[i];

            if (digit !== 0) {
                isZero = false;
            }

            digits[i] = digit / 10 >>> 0;
            carry = digit % 10;
        }

        if (isZero) {
            break;
        }

        result.push(carry);
    }

    return result.reverse().join('') || '0';
};

const ALPHABET = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

console.log(decode(ALPHABET, '1Zpvmcf1O26').padStart(19, '0'));
```

Using ASCII digits and letters (62) gives results of up to length 11 for inputs of 19 digits. If you can put more characters in the alphabet with no problems at all, like if you’re trying to fit as many 19-digit strings as possible in a tweet to be read by a machine, do so – each additional character makes some number of inputs shorter (but the returns are diminishing).

If you need to be compatible with older browsers, mind that the `const alphabet = Array.from(alphabetString)` is only necessary when using characters that require multiple UTF-16 code units. With only ASCII, you can delete that line and rename `alphabetString` to `alphabet`.

Comment: Thank for your solution. I couldn't use db on my host, but now I am using mlab for hosting db separately, so I use it for storing id - shorId couples. In any case, it looks like best solution for this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

There are some libs on npm that would do that for you. [This one for example](http://js-string-compression)

Here is the [RunKit example](https://runkit.com/akrion/js-string-compress)

You can also pick his brain here: https://github.com/cschen1205/js-string-compression/blob/master/src/jsscompress.js

And there is [lzutf8](https://github.com/rotemdan/lzutf8.js) which would give you something like this:

```js
var l = require("lzutf8")

var result = l.compress('asdasdsadsadsadsadsadsadaseqwrewqasdsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadfgweg43g', {outputEncoding: 'Base64' })
console.log(result)

//"YXNkYXNkc2HQA2FzZXF3cmV3cdUe1QNmZ3dlZzQzZw=="

var result2 = l.decompress(result, {inputEncoding: 'Base64'})
console.log(result2) 

// "asdasdsadsadsadsadsadsadaseqwrewqas…adsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadfgweg43g"
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to compress the data you have, but just a head's up, typical compression algorithms wouldn't give you much of a drastic compression result for so small input.

There is [this](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) library for zlib related things in JavaScript which you can use to deflate your input.

```
// For shortening your input
function shorten(input) {
  const compressed = pako.deflate(input);
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, compressed));
}
// For getting the original value
function revert(compressed) {
  const decompressed = pako.inflate(compressed);
  return atob(btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, decompressed)));
}
```

You can send the return value of the `shorten` function to the server and the server can use the `revert` function to decompress the string again.

Something to play with:

```js
function cmprs(input) {
  const compressed = pako.deflate(input);
  return {
    base64: btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, compressed)),
    binary: compressed
  };
}
function revert(compressed) {
  const decompressed = pako.inflate(compressed);
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, decompressed));
}

document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("keyup", ev => {
  const value = ev.target.value;
  document.querySelector("#output").textContent = cmprs(value).base64;
  document.querySelector("#decompressed").textContent = atob(
    revert(cmprs(value).binary)
  );
});
```

```html
<input id="input" />
<br />
Output: <span id="output"></span>
<br />
Decompressed: <span id="decompressed"></span>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pako/1.0.6/pako.js"></script>
<script src="src/index.js"></script>
```

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rw6n9wowjo)

Comment: I already saw some libs for compressing string, but all of this return byte sequence, but I didn`t know, that there is a way to transform it to string. Thank for your snippet.